# Textarea behaves weirdly when data is displayed in division

Tags: jquery, html

I have:

```
<textarea id='txtSomeId'><p><span>. </span><span>&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;</span><span>Bullet one </span> </p> </textarea>
```

When I use jQuery's `$("#txtSomeId").val()` and display it in a division like `$("divId").html($("#txtSomeId").val());`
 some wierd characters appeared like `[[[][]][][][][` instead of `&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;`. This happens when I paste text in Google Chrome and save it and view the data in IE.

If I view it in Google Chrome then I don't get this issue but when I view data saved from Google Chrome in IE I get this issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nbsp;` should be `&nbsp;`, that is what I see at the first look

Comment: sorry.. but in actual the style set was like style ="font-family:Symbol" where this wierd charaters where appearing

Comment: any ways I replaced such style or removed and now every thing is working file thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to have html inside a textarea. Use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to solve this.